# GitHub Desktop: Git could not be found at the expected path

Tags: git, github

I am new to GitHub and I am having trouble creating a new repo:

before-

[image: before]

After:

Then I get this error msg:

```
Git could not be found at the expected path: 
  '/Users/user/Downloads/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/git/bin/git'. 
This might be a problem with how the application is packaged, 
so confirm this folder hasn't been removed when packaging.
```

What do I do?
Do I need to place my files in a certain folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try instead to:

- create your repo on github.com (not through GitHub Desktop)
- use git clone https://github.com//.git to clone it in `/path/to/project1`

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git /path/to/project1
  ```
- import that path (drag and drop) into GitHub Desktop

As [Kamaltejveerapaneni](https://github.com/Kamaltejveerapaneni) commented in [issue 1638](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1638#issuecomment-350938421) (and confirmed below in another issue):

> Its working fine when I reinstalled it

Answer (score 6):

This question has been answered here : https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4165
and it works to me. I repeat the process below:

1. restart your computer
2. uninstall GitHub Desktop
3. delete
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHubDesktop\ and %APPDATA%\GitHub Desktop
4. install GitHub Desktop again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your GitHub Desktop's config:

> Git could not be found at the expected path: '/Users/user/Downloads/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/git/bin/git'.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you